# Need the exit code of condition function when a Bash "while" loop terminates

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling

I'm trying to get the exit code of the function that I'm repeatedly calling in the "condition" part of a Bash `while` loop:

```bash
while <function>; do 
    <stuff> 
done
```

When this loop terminates due to an error, I need the exit code of `<function>`.  Any thoughts on how I can get that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can capture the exit value from the condition and propagate that forward:

```
while rmdir FOO; ss=$?; [[ $ss -eq 0 ]]
do
    echo in loop
done
echo "out of loop with ?=$? but ss=$ss"
```

Output

```
rmdir: failed to remove 'FOO': No such file or directory
out of loop with ?=0 but ss=1
```

In this instance the exit status from `rmdir FOO` has been captured in the variable `ss` and is `1`. (Try replacing `rmdir FOO` with `( exit 4 )`. You'll find that `ss=4`.)

How does this work? Remember that the syntax is actually `while list-1; do list-2; done`, and not the much more usual expectation of `while command; do list; done`. The `list-1` can be a sequence of semicolon-separated commands, and the documentation states that the "*`while` command continuously executes the list `list-2` as long as the last command in the list `list-1` returns an exit status of zero.*"

As an alternative presentation of the messy-looking `while` condition, it is possible to assign a variable while inside an expression `(( ... ))`, and then to use the result. This gives the harder-to-read but more compact assign-and-test structure:

```
while rmdir FOO; ((! (ss=$?)))
do
    echo in loop
done
echo "out of loop with ?=$? but ss=$ss"
```

Alternatively you can use `while rmdir FOO; ! (( ss=$? ))`.  These work because ((1)) evaluates arithmetically to 1, which is generally associated with true, and so the exit code of that evaluation is 0 (success). On the other hand, ((0)) evaluates arithmetically to 0, which is generally associated with false, and so the exit code of that evaluation is 1 (failure). This may seem confusing, as after all both evaluations `((.))` are "successful", but this is a hack to bring the value of arithmetic expressions representing true/false in line with bash's exit codes of success/failure, and make conditional expressions like `if ...; then ...; fi`, `while ...; do ...; done`, etc, work correctly, whether based on exit codes or arithmetic values.

Comment: Actually, roaima, I have a question here. Those inner most ()'s around the assignment. What do they mean? I'm not aware of that bit of syntax.  And then, why doesn't `something like [[ $(ss=$?) -eq 0 ]]` work?

Comment: The brackets in `(ss=$?)` are purely to force the assignment before anything else. Your `[[ $(ss=$?) -eq 0 ]]` can't work because it tries to evaluate `ss=$?` as a command

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but from the man page, "(list) list  is  executed  in  a  subshell  environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below)."  If that's a subshell (?) then ss wouldn't be defined when returning out of that shell (?)

Comment: @Diagon `(( (ss=$!) ))` has no subshells; it's all expression evaluation. Like `(( (1+2)*3 ))` where the `*` isn't a filename glob but a multiplication symbol

Comment: Ok, much appreciated, thank you.  Bash, as you perhaps see, is often as obscure as the fog to me.

Comment: Yes, I found it.  Under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION, "Operators are evaluated in order of precedence.  Sub-expressions in parentheses are evaluated first and may override the precedence rules above."

Comment: if you want to golf it, use `! ((ss=$?))` and save the parens...

Comment: @ilkkachu & @roaima - what remains mysterious to me, is how it is that if `rmdir FOO` returns success ("0"), then the `while rmdir FOO` loop proceeds; but a `while rmdir FOO; (($?))` loop fails?  In the first case, the `rmdir FOO` is giving an exit code of `0`, which is read as "true", while in the second case that `0` is being evaluated and turned into a `0`, which is then read as "false."  How is it that these two `0`'s are different?

Comment: @Diagon, because the shell is weird. In C, and in most programming language, if you convert a number to an boolean (a true/false value), a zero becomes false, and anything else becomes true. So, in C, `if (x) foo();` will call `foo()` if `x` is _nonzero_. The arithmetic context that the shell uses inside `(( .. ))` mimics that behaviour, it exits with a falsy status if the final value inside is _zero_. That's actually ok in something like `while (( i-- ))`, which would count down until `i` is zero.

Comment: Just that in the shell, when we're looking at the exit status of a command, zero is _truthy_ (and everything else falsy). Unlike the convention everywhere else, and unlike the convention inside `(( .. ))` in the shell... Hence the extra negation here. Doing it that way does have the upside that there's more codes to use for the various different failure cases (all happy families being alike, but the unhappy ones varying), but I'm also pretty convinced the original Unix creators were high on something far more often than the Unix users of today can be...

Comment: @ilkkachu - I see, yes.  `((1)); echo $?` returns `0`.  This all almost making me want to learn python, because it's so convoluted.  I can't imagine writing a bash parser.  It all just seems to convoluted and often backwards.

Comment: @ilkkachu I wasn't intentionally playing golf, but thank you :-)

Comment: @Diagon it comes from the desire to be able to use a status code to report one success or multiple failure types. Zero becomes success ("no errors") and all the non-zeros become various types of failure.

Comment: @Diagon, yes, that's a feeling that comes easily if one starts to implement anything complex in the shell. Just that if you're calling external commands a lot, other languages need a bit more plumbing for that, so, yeah. And please let's not talk about having to _implement_ a shell parser (or a lexer), I'd like to sleep without nightmares...

Comment: @ilkkachu - Ok, this really was confusing.  I got it straightened out [on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950760/1618452).  The key is, `((1))` evaluates arithmetically to `1`, which is generally associated with `true`, and so the exit code of that evaluation is `0` (success).  On the other hand, `((0))` evaluates arithmetically to `0`, which is generally associated with `false`, and so the exit code of that evaluation is `1` (failure).  This brings true/false in line with success/failure, and makes conditional loops work properly, whether based on exit codes or arithmetic values.

Comment: @roaima - would it be ok if one of us edits your answer to add clarification about this last point (my just previous comment).

Comment: @Diagon, yes, it could help a bit to consider the shell `if` in terms of success and failure, and not true and false. And if you look at the POSIX text, they are careful to not say "true" or "false" in conjunction with conditionals and exit statuses but instead say "if the exit status is zero" or so. But that's a hard distinction to consistently keep, since probably everywhere else conditionals are associated with truthiness. And e.g. Bash's manual isn't as consistent on avoiding "true", and the POSIX text has a slip in the examples for `exit`, there it says `exit 0` "exits with a true value".

Comment: (and of course there are the utilities called `true` and `false` that respectively exit with a status indicating success and failure...)

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to make the test explicitly instead of delegating it to `while`. So, the following should do:

```bash
err=0
while true
do
    <function>
    (( (err=$?) > 0 )) && break
    <stuff>
done
echo "$err"
```

At the beginning of the (a priori infinite) loop you would execute the condition command "manually" and store the exit code, check it, and break out of the loop if it is non-zero (indicating failure). Only if it was zero you execute the "actual" loop code.

The syntax can be "compacted" because (as noted by @roaima) you can have variable assignments inside the `(( ... ))` arithmetic test construct.

Answer (score 4):

Create a wrapping function that sets a variable with the result of the exit code of your function. Example:

```bsh
e=0

# file does not exist
foo() { 
  rm xyz
}

baz() { 
  foo
  e=$?
  [[ $e -ne 0 ]] && return 1
  return 0
}

# create a file
touch xyz
while baz; do
  # first loop succeeds, the file exists
  # second loop exits with error, file doesn't exists
  echo in loop
done
```

```
in loop
rm: cannot remove 'xyz': No such file or directory
```

```
# then
$ echo $e
1
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Define `foo()` and `baz()` as above. The loop becomes `touch xyz; while baz; do echo in loop; done; echo $e`. I don't ever get an "`in loop`" message. It looks like the `[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return` should be replaced as `[[ $e -ne 0 ]] && return 1; return 0`, which in turn can be replaced as `[[ $e -eq 0]]` with no explicit `return` statement

Comment: @roaima I edited with your suggestions, if you think it can be improved, feel free to edit if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you could use `return` from an anonymous function:

```
() while ((1)) {
  <function> || return
  <stuff>
}
print $?
```

With any Bourne-like shell, you can always use a named function:

```
repeat_until_fail()
  while true; do
    <function> || return
    <stuff>
  done

repeat_until_fail
echo "$?"
```